# DataGridView Delete rows in it

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have One question
In My Grid get info from 6 sql server table. i have button which deletes  current row with one by one.  Is there any simple way to make this ?
I think my question is not clearly asked so...
So my btnDelete get ids from sql Tables and then goes and delete rows in 6 tables.
Im using 4.0 c# winForms.
my grid source is datatable which i fill with sqlDataReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to delete that all the rows displayed in a grid by the click on one Delete button.
Why don't use the criteria that used to select the rows to delete the same, instead of deleting row by row?
That would be pretty quick.